ERROR: No matching issuer found when using Selenium and ChromeDriver
New to Selenium and getting these errors when trying to run my Python file. How do I fix them?
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51668/devtools/browser/dfc02c1e-6061-459c-973b-ede6b1e45e84
[35196:41600:0514/105526.328:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(1052)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for wpad failed:
----- Certificate i=0 (CN=self-signedKey,O=Sagemcom Ca,C=FR) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[35196:23000:0514/105526.376:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(1052)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for wpad failed:
----- Certificate i=0 (CN=self-signedKey,O=Sagemcom Ca,C=FR) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[35196:23000:0514/105526.385:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(1052)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for wpad failed:
----- Certificate i=0 (CN=self-signedKey,O=Sagemcom Ca,C=FR) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

Selenium seems to be working as a new window with google pops up and I have ChromeDriver installed properly but I'm not sure what those errors are. I have tried the options arguments below from other posts but they don't fix my problem. This is my code right now.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
# options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
# options.add_argument("--disable-proxy-certificate-handler")
# options.add_argument("--disable-content-security-policy")
service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com")

#time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()


seems like a cert used by a proxy on your network... the error is saying that the issuer is not from a trustedCA which is normal for internal proxies. (corporate environment?)  I would just ignore the errors unless they stop your tests, but you could also create a profile manually, add the cert to the trusted store and configure chromeoptions to use that profile.  Chances are that cert is already added as trusted in your default profile.

as already mentioned by @browsermator in the comments, this error can probably safely be ignored.
To hide the log from chromedriver (=> Chrome), you can modify your script as following:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# hide log
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com")

#time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()

